# Should I use [sic] when quoting sexist language?

Tags: sic

From R. P. Feynman, "The character of physical law":

> If it disagrees with experiment, it's wrong. In that simple statement is the key to science. It doesn't make any difference how beautiful your guess is, it doesn't make any difference how smart you are, who made the guess, or what his name is. If it disagrees with experiment, it's wrong. That's all there is to it.

Feynman is assuming here that a scientist must be male. Should I point this out by adding [sic] after "his"?

Comment: Just as soon as you pay your telepathy bill. "Feynman is assuming..."

Comment: *Sic* follows a grammatical error or spelling error in someone's writing so as to not be confused as a typo by the one transcribing it.  Where you've gotten the idea that it's for expressing your negative opinion about the author's perfectly grammatical and orthographic wording, I don't know, but you'll have to source it if you want this question to stand.

Comment: Have you considered *or what [their] name is*?

Comment: Just consider the usage grand[parented].

Comment: The simple answer is no. In any case, it's not up to you to decide what is sexist and what is not. Feynman's observations where made before all this politically correct nonsense flared up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not. [Sic] is used to avoid culpability for grammatical, spelling, or style errors in quoted text - it basically means "this does not match my style manual". The thing is, the use of *his* or *he* to denote a generic third person of unspecified gender has been acceptable for a very long time. If you put [sic] after it, many readers may not be able to identify the "error" that you're calling attention to. [Sic] should only answer questions that the reader might have (was that actually the quote or just a misprint?), not raise questions (what's wrong with this quote at all?).

Although the use of gender-specific pronouns is falling out of favor, Feynman's quote is perfectly grammatical and does not necessarily assume a gender - he's working within the limitations of the English language, as there are no universally accepted, gender-neutral, third-person pronouns that can directly replace *he* or *she*. Putting [sic] here will probably only confuse the reader.

Comment: Fair enough. However, "this does not match my style manual" is exactly what that [sic] would mean.

Comment: @nemarona Yes, that's why it wouldn't be entirely wrong to include a [sic], but for many readers, it will be unclear what, exactly, does not match your style manual (was it the pronoun, punctuation, grammar, or something else I'm missing?). If the style you're correcting is not obviously wrong to the reader, they will not glean any information from the [sic], and it will only serve to obfuscate the text.

Comment: @NuclearWang I'd put the [sic] immediately after "his" - so it's pretty obvious what is being referred to.

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem like a very normal usage of "sic" as it related to changing social norms, rather than a misspelling or error, per se. Is there no way you could provide some context outside the quote -- i.e. a line of your own afterwards?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, this is not sexist. The use of "his" here is because in Feynman's time the singular "they," the correct pronoun, was highly discouraged. Essentially, in an attempt to make English more like Latin, English writers would use the masculine as a gender-neutral pronoun (because, due to slightly complicated linguistic reasons*, that's how it's done in Latin) instead of the correct singular "they." That is what is occurring here. So,

## Putting [sic] here is acceptable.

English is not Latin, and as much as old style guides (like the ones Feynman would have been using) will tell you otherwise, you can't use a masculine pronoun to refer to a gender-indeterminate antecedent.

**The linguistic reason is that Proto-Indo-European (PIE), from which Latin and English both developed, originally had one gender (what is now the masculine) and not three. The neuter was developed later to refer to inanimate objects, so the masculine referred to animate objects. Finally the feminine was created for abstract nouns like "philosophia." So in a group containing a person, an object, and a concept, the person obviously takes precedence, and in Latin that is exactly what happens.*

Comment: "Putting [sic] here is acceptable." Perhaps, but calling *singular they* "the correct pronoun" is not. I switched to it 1980 in defiance of the current style guide, but I would never call it that and most people I know consider it weird.

Comment: Proto-Indo-European originally is believed to have ***two*** genders, the animate and the inanimate. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals). And splitting animate into masculine and feminine is perfectly reasonable, and undoubtedly happened for reasons of actual gender, and not for abstract nouns like "philosophia" (although these do generally tend to be feminine).

Answer (score -2):

As an undergraduate in 1991 (30 years ago) I was taught that it is not acceptable to let quoted, historically-sexist language pass without some acknowledgement. Unless you are writing a paper about historical gender norms, I suggest you use "he [sic]". In your own writing, use "they" as a singular pronoun. If you need backup, insert a footnote telling the reader that The Chicago Manual of Style has accepted the singular form of "they / them / their" since 2017. The times, they are a-changin' ...